# Find out null values between two columns in a DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I have to check if there any Null values in between the two columns I have in Dataframe. I have fetched the location of the first non null value and the last non value in the dataframe using these :

```
 x.first_valid_index()
 x.last_valid_index()
```

Now i need to find if there any null values in between these two locations

Comment: Can you add some example data?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is same as check all `NaN` values to `boolean mask` and sum `True` values:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,np.nan, np.nan],
                  'b':[np.nan, 7,np.nan,np.nan],
                  'c':[4,5,6,np.nan]})
print (x)
     a    b    c
0  1.0  NaN  4.0
1  2.0  7.0  5.0
2  NaN  NaN  6.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN


cols = ['a','b']
f = x[cols].first_valid_index()
l = x[cols].last_valid_index()
print (f)
0
print (l)
1

print (x.loc[f:l, cols].isnull().sum().sum())
1
```

Comment: I need to check if there are any null values between the columns i have . How to that that ?

Comment: Can you add sample? Do you think check NaNs only in 2 columns or there are multiple columns?

Comment: In this case the Columns A,B,C have numeric values , but in my case I have column names which I to want to add or do any kind of operation which can tell me if they are any null values in between those columns.

Comment: Hmm, can you modify my dataframe as you need and add to question with desired output? thanks.